# Reading and writing text files in C#

Tags: c#, text

I am coding a program where I need to read, write, and filter data from one text file to a new one.
The main goal of this program is:

- have the user select a text file with data that I have already created,
- use a Substring to choose which characters to grab from the file,
- write a file that matches the data from the text file.

I am a little stuck on getting the program to write files in general as well as grabbing certain characters from a text file.
If anyone could give me some pointers that would be awesome.
Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Project_4_osmvoe
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string ham;
        StreamReader pizza;
        StreamWriter burger;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ham = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
            pizza = new StreamReader(ham);
            lblInputFile.Text = ham;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ham = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
            burger = new StreamWriter(ham);
            lblOutputFile.Text = ham;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = pizza.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (filter(line))
                    burger.WriteLine(line);
            }
            pizza.Close();
            burger.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Output File Written");
        }

        private Boolean filter(string intext)
        {
            string gender = intext.Substring(0, 0);
            string state = intext.Substring(0, 0);
            if (((radioButtonFemale.Checked && gender.Equals("F")) ||
                 (RadioButtonMale.Checked && gender.Equals("M"))))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I seriously hope those aren't your real variable names...

Comment: Also use the method `Dispose();` for the StreamWriter/Reader. `Close()` is insufficient.

Comment: What problem are you having, specifically?

Comment: Whenever I load up the text file with the open file dialogue and attempt to transfer the contents, no text appears on the new file. It is just a blank text document.

Comment: Your entire program flow seems completely wrong to me... don't keep a streamreader/writer open, keep it encapsulated within a method and either store or pass around its contents in a list or an array.. apart from the obvious memory leak of repeatedly clicking button1/button2, your just asking for trouble by keeping the file open longer than its needed

Comment: Your variable names look like you barfed up dinner from last night!  Seriously though wrapping Streams in using blocks is generally your best bet to keep from leaking resources.

Answer (score 6):

A part from the useful advices received in the comments above.
(Don't keep streams opened between events)

What do you think is the result of these lines?

```
    string gender = intext.Substring(0, 0);
    string state = intext.Substring(0, 0);
```

THe second parameter of `Substring` is the number of chars to extract from the string. Passing zero means that your returned string is empty, so the subsequent test is always false and you never write a line.

I suggest to store, in two different global variables, the names of the two files and, in button3_Click open the two streams

```
string inputFile;
string outputFile;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        inputFile = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        lblInputFile.Text = inputFile;
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        outputFile = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
        lblOutputFile.Text = outputFile ;
    }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string line;
    using(StreamReader pizza = new StreamReader(inputFile))
    using(StreamWriter burger = new StreamWrite(outputFile))
    {
        while ((line = pizza.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) && filter(line))
               burger.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Output File Written");
}

private Boolean filter(string intext)
{
    string gender = intext.Substring(0, 1);
    string state = intext.Substring(0, 1);
    if (((radioButtonFemale.Checked && gender.Equals("F")) ||
         (RadioButtonMale.Checked && gender.Equals("M"))))
         return true;
    else
         return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see what you are saying however I have a problem no matter what numbers I put into the Substring. I have tried to put (0,1) because that is the character I want to be transferred but I get an error.

Comment: Wish I could give more than +1 for the effort here, Steve.. kudos

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Comment: So, you have some empty lines in your input file, reading 1 character from an empty line, well it is obvious. Now, what you want to do with those empty lines. Write them on the output stream or filter them out?

Comment: I do not want any empty lines at all, so I guess filter them out. The weird thing is my text file begins with characters on line 0 and ends at line 1, which is what I want. But I still get this error.

Comment: Added a check for null, empty or lines with just white spaces. For the rest of your problem, you are the only one that can look at your input file and check what characters it contains. Use the debugger to step by step the code in button3_click